# Need help trying to code in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to coding and I am trying to code in Python 3 the following:

```
How many students?: 4
How many units?: 3
What is the name of student 1?: John
What did John get in unit 1?: 34
34 out of 100 is a Fail.
What did John get in unit 2?: 67
67 out of 100 is a Credit.
What did John get in unit 3?: 52
52 out of 100 is a Pass.
On average, John is getting a Pass.
```

Then after it does this for all 4 students, the program has to say: The top score is (Student Name) with an average score of (Student score).

This is what I have so far. How can I get it to loop through the students information individually as above? Mine comes out one after another.

```
numStudent = int (input('Please enter number of students: '))
numUnit = int(input('Please enter the number of units for your course: '))

for i in range(numStudent):
      studentName = input('Please enter students first name: ')

for j in range(numUnit):

    unitmark = int(input('what did' + ' ' + studentName + ' ' + 'get for unit:'))

def calculateGrade(unitmark):

    if unitmark <= 49:
        Print(unitmark,"out of 100 You are failing")
    elif unitmark <= 59:
        return(unitmark,"out of 100 is a Pass")
    elif unitmark <=69:
        return(unitmark, "out of 100 is a Credit")
    elif unitmark <= 79:
        return(unitmark, "out of 100 is a Distinction")
    elif unitmark <=100:
        return(unitmark, "out of 100 is a High Distinction")

print(calculateGrade(unitmark))           

totalGrade = numUnit + unitmark

averageGrade = totalGrade / 100

print(round (averageGrade, 7))
```

Comment: Pls, fix the post. It is poorly understandable.

Comment: Sorry,when I pasted it in it just came up like this, how do I fix it?

Comment: A quick search will help you with formatting: [How to format code in Stack Overflow?](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=How+to+format+code+in+Stack+Overflow%3F)

Comment: This will not have been seen by many `python` tag watchers, as it was tagged as `p`. I've re-tagged it, and re-formatted it.

Comment: @Jules, I can help you. Tell me, how do you want to run your code? Via command line, or would you like to call a function in a Python shell?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. Run in IDLE or if you are on Linux run it in terminal, for example `python3.6 ./grades.py` (specify correct Python version and create grades.py)

```
def get_grade(score, name=None):
    if score <= 49:
        grade = "You are failing"
    elif score <= 59:
        grade = "is a Pass"
    elif score <= 69:
        grade =  "is a Credit"
    elif score <= 79:
        grade =  "is a Distinction"
    elif score <= 100:
        grade =  "is a High Distinction"

    if not name:
        print(score, "out of 100", grade)
    else:
        print('On average,', name, grade)

num_students = int(input('How many students?: '))
num_units = int(input('How many units?: '))

students_db = {}

for student_num in range(1, num_students+1):
    student_name = input('\nWhat is the name of student %s?: ' % student_num)

    current_student_total_scores = 0
    for unit_num in range(1, num_units+1):
        unitmark = int(input('\nWhat did %s get in unit %s?: ' % (student_name, unit_num)))
        current_student_total_scores += unitmark
        get_grade(unitmark)

    avarage_score = current_student_total_scores/num_units
    get_grade(avarage_score, student_name)

    students_db.update({student_name: avarage_score})

name, avg_score = max(students_db.items(), key = lambda p: p[1])
print('\nThe top score is %s with an average score of %s' % (name, avg_score))
```

Dont forget to accept the answer :)